# Kotlin Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit

Hi i have problem with retrofit and api. I used api from this:
https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds i add my auth key

This is my model with plugin kotlin data class:

```
data class CatsItem(
    @SerializedName("adaptability")
    val adaptability: Int,
    @SerializedName("affection_level")
    val affectionLevel: Int,
    @SerializedName("alt_names")
    val altNames: String,
    @SerializedName("bidability")
    val bidability: Int,
    @SerializedName("cat_friendly")
    val catFriendly: Int,
    @SerializedName("cfa_url")
    val cfaUrl: String,
    @SerializedName("child_friendly")
    val childFriendly: Int,
    @SerializedName("country_code")
    val countryCode: String,
    @SerializedName("country_codes")
    val countryCodes: String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String,
    @SerializedName("dog_friendly")
    val dogFriendly: Int,
    @SerializedName("energy_level")
    val energyLevel: Int,
    @SerializedName("experimental")
    val experimental: Int,
    @SerializedName("grooming")
    val grooming: Int,
    @SerializedName("hairless")
    val hairless: Int,
    @SerializedName("health_issues")
    val healthIssues: Int,
    @SerializedName("hypoallergenic")
    val hypoallergenic: Int,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("indoor")
    val indoor: Int,
    @SerializedName("intelligence")
    val intelligence: Int,
    @SerializedName("lap")
    val lap: Int,
    @SerializedName("life_span")
    val lifeSpan: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("natural")
    val natural: Int,
    @SerializedName("origin")
    val origin: String,
    @SerializedName("rare")
    val rare: Int,
    @SerializedName("rex")
    val rex: Int,
    @SerializedName("shedding_level")
    val sheddingLevel: Int,
    @SerializedName("short_legs")
    val shortLegs: Int,
    @SerializedName("social_needs")
    val socialNeeds: Int,
    @SerializedName("stranger_friendly")
    val strangerFriendly: Int,
    @SerializedName("suppressed_tail")
    val suppressedTail: Int,
    @SerializedName("temperament")
    val temperament: String,
    @SerializedName("vcahospitals_url")
    val vcahospitalsUrl: String,
    @SerializedName("vetstreet_url")
    val vetstreetUrl: String,
    @SerializedName("vocalisation")
    val vocalisation: Int,
    @SerializedName("weight")
    val weight: Weight,
    @SerializedName("wikipedia_url")
    val wikipediaUrl: String
)
```

This is my response :

```
>  viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Response", response.body()?.id.toString())
               massage.text = response.body()?.name.toString()
                

            } else {
                Log.d("Response", response.errorBody().toString())
                errormassage.text = response.code().toString()
            }
        })
```

I wanna show in textView breeds name but i have error when i run app:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

What i do wrong?

Thanks for any tips and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting JSON from the URL you indicate returns an array of objects. If this whole response is what's in `response.body()` in the success case, then your code is failing to deal that response correctly. It is assuming that the returned structure consists of a single object rather than an array of objects.

In other words, the result coming back looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": 1234
    }
]
```

but your code is expecting:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": 1234
}
```

If you're not sure, why don't you print out the value of `response.body()` to see what's in there?

If this is what's going on, a fix would look like this:

```
response.body()?.get(0).name.toString()
```

to operate on the first item in the array. (Or something like that.  I have done very little with Kotlin vs Java, so maybe there's another `?` in there or something.)